# Do normal random number generators give a specified sample mean or population mean?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, random-generation

Do normal random number generators like R's `rnorm` give a specified sample mean or population mean?

For example does the mean argument in R's `rnorm()` function give  "mean =sample mean" or "mean=population mean"?

I am wondering this ...then like say I have a set of real data set, then can I just calculate the sample mean and sample standard deviation ,and put them into this function?

Comment: rnorm() generates a random set of numbers based on a mean and standard deviation (default is mean=0, sd=1).  It has nothing to do with the sample of a population.

Comment: I've edited your post to ask essentially the same question in a way that's more nearly on topic. I am sorry but I couldn't figure out what you mean in your last paragraph so I just left it. Can you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Normal random number generators simulate (pseudo-) random numbers from the normal *distribution* that has the specified mean and standard deviation. That is to say, you specify the population mean and population standard deviation.

That the mean argument is not the sample mean is trivial to check by generating a sample of size 1. e.g. in R:

```
rnorm(1,mean=0,s=1)
 [1] 1.05083
```

The sample mean of that sample we just generated isn't 0.

Similar comments apply to other distributions -- you're specifying population parameters.

If you calculate the sample mean of some other sample and put that in as the value of the mean argument of a normal random number generator, that will be the population mean for the new sample you generate (even though you took it from the mean of some other sample).

Comment: For example : i have a data set of n1=141, n2=68, xbar1=3.06,xbar2=3.82, sd1=0.95 and sd2=0.41, then if i wish to do a simulation by using t-test. Then x<-rnorm(m,xbar1,sd1) and y <-rnorm(n,xbar2,sd2) .Is this right?

Comment: because i do not know the exact population mean and population variance. I have only a set of data ...

Comment: But then why are you generating random numbers with the same mean and variance?

Comment: I generate them so that i can perform t-test and simulation ....@@ I am losing my ideas....

Comment: How would generating random numbers allow you to perform a t-test? What's the simulation for?

Comment: The simulation is for robustness checking. I have found a set of real data set then i have to use them to do one time simulation, and compare the real data set's simulation result with my simulated results (this is just not a real data)

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're doing there, but putting a sample mean in for the mean argument will generate a sample from a distribution which has as its population mean the sample mean you gave it as already described in my answer.